# Trying to filter through objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to loop over some objects that has '_order' included in the key, and make sure that their value is greater than the `${section.name}_order` and return those items.

What am I doing wrong? :)

```
const sectionsAfter = Object.keys(res.data()).filter((item) => (
    item.includes('_order') && res.data()[item] > `${section.name}_order`
))
```

### Update

I was providing the wrong data. `${section.name}_order` wasn't returning the value I was after. It's now working as expected :)

Comment: You are comparing with text. `${section.name}_order` is template literal - a string

Comment: Please provide a sample of `res.data()` and expecting result of `sectionsAfter`

Comment: Also you probably want filtered object, not filtered object keys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure the `${section.name}_order` is string or number.
If `${section.name}_order` is number then you shouldn't add ` around `${section.name}_order`. It will become string.

Answer (score 1):

You are compare with the template string `${section.name}_order`

You need get value of `${section.name}_order`